# Integral $ g(a)= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\arctan(a \tan x)}{\tan x}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble calculating this integral:

$$ g(a) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\arctan(a \tan x)}{\tan x}dx $$

I tried calculating $g'(a)$ but then I get stuck.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.

Comment: A right place fo such questions is MSE.

Comment: Both [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Carctan(a%20%5Ctan%20x)%7D%7B%5Ctan%20x%7Ddx%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Carctan(a%20%5Ctan%20x)%7D%7B%5Ctan%20x%7Ddx%20%7D$) lead to this post: [Derivating with respect the parameter calcule $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\arctan(a\tan x)}{\tan x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2531894) (It is closed, but still you can see a solution there.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 
$$g(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \,  \text{sgn}(a) \ln(1+|a|)
$$
for real $a$.

This can be obtained as follows: $g(0)=0$ and 
$$g'(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{(1+a^2u^2)(1+u^2)}=\frac{\pi/2}{1+|a|},
$$
where we used the substitution $u=\tan x$; 
the latter integral can be taken by partial fraction decomposition: 
$$\frac1{(1+a^2u^2)(1+u^2)}=\frac{1}{\left(1-a^2\right)
   \left(1+u^2\right)} - 
\frac{a^2}{(1-a^2) \left(1+a^2 u^2\right)}
$$
for real $a$ with $|a|\ne1$; the case $|a|=1$ can be obtained by continuity.

Comment: Sorry, but my Mathematica 12.0 by Integrate[ArcTan[a*Tan[x]]/Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}] produces ConditionalExpression[1/4 \[Pi] (2 ArcTanh[Abs[a]]+Log[1-a^2]) Sign[a],a \ [Element] Reals]. I check it for $a=\frac 1 2$ numerically. In my personal opinion a right place for the question and answer is MSE.

Comment: @user64494 : (i) Yes, Mathematica is imperfect. Here you have to work a bit to simplify the expression. Alternatively, you can use Integrate[ArcTan[a Tan[x]]/Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> a > 0] to get 1/2 \[Pi] Log[1 + a]. I have now removed the reference to Mathematica anyway, since I gave an explicit derivation without using Mathematica. (ii) As to whether this question is OK for MO, I am not sure; I could imagine it arise in some research.

Comment: (ii) This is Demidovich 3734 https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wdh380ok6eqazj/Demidovich%203734.docx?dl=0

Comment: @user64494 : Good find!